# Why is Github Enterprise a committer of all merge commits?

Tags: github, github-enterprise

When I merge a PR on GitHub, the committer of a merge commit is always "GitHub Enterprise". The author still points to my account.

This is how it looks on my repository

```
Commit 2:
  - the message is "Merge pull request #xx from branch" as it was created by PR
  - the author is me, but the committer is GitHub Enterprise

Commit 1:
  - this is the original commit from which I created a PR
  - both the author and committer are me
```

I can't find any settings related to changing a committer. I also don't think that there is any hooks that overrides a committer.

Answer (score 2):

You did the merge in the GitHub UI and is was the GitHub website that made the actual commit and stored it on your behalf.

- In case you did a fast-forward merge, the commit would be authored by you and committed by you.
- If you do a squash merge in the UI, the server needs to create a new squashed commit on yours behalf, so the committer and the author wouldn't be the same.
- If you do a merge commit (--no-ff) in the UI, the server needs to create a merge commit on your behalf, so the committer and the author wouldn't be the same.
- If you did all the work locally and pushed directly to the target branch (probably blocked by policy), the UI wouldn't have to do anything on your behalf.
- If you did all the work locally and created a fast-forward merge ready branch and ff-merged that through the pull request, the server won't need to make a commit on your behalf either.